# Open RDLC Report in a pop up window in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, popup, rdlc

I want to know how to open a RDLC Report in a new pop up(not on new tab but a seperate pop-up window). I have taken an asp.net web application. I have added a .rdlc and created a dataset and a report with the data from datasaet.

I have a report view model from where i am getting the data to render the report. Now i have a view report button. When I click on viewReport which is a @HTML.ActionLink(), the report  should open as a popup.

I had followed this link: [RDLC Report in MVC Web Application](http://ata2931977.blogspot.sg/2012/07/rdlc-reports-in-mvc-web-application.html)

Please suggest me on how to approach and also provide any links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That depends one the libs that you are using, to generate popups.
If you aren't using any js lib and it's ok to open a new window on browser, use target="_blank".
That will cause the link to open in a new window, so that "href"/route just need to return a full html page with the report.
If you want something more fancy, please tell the libs that you are using, for me to help you.

Comment: but when i use target="_blank", the new browser window opens in a new tab which i don't want. I want that my report file should open as a pop-up file and not in a new window/tab...
(thanks for your concern)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to render the report viewer in a section or div that is invisible, and make it visible, using JavaScript, to pop up, when you want to show your report. It will be much easier if you use one of the *Window* plug-ins for this, such as the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default).